# Shadow over Mystara how to manage the cursed sword

Tags: dnd-shadow-over-mystara

I know that some characters can equip the cursed sword, but they can't use it properly. How can we 'break' this curse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Two Cursed Swords.

The first one randomly wounds the user for every swing. Swing it around 30 times and it might transform in the Sword of Legend

The second one randomly paralyzes the user for every swing. Pick it with the Cleric 8 times and it becomes the Holy Avenger